# Eglot introduces strange parentheses behavior, conflict with electric-pair-mode

Tags: eglot, electric-pair-mode

I am using Emacs 30.0.5 and eglot 1.16. I found a strange behavior when eglot is enabled in a buffer. When I enter a left parenthesis `(` at one side of a function call parameter, the other parenthesis `)` will automatically be entered on the other side of the parameter. Let `|` indicate my cursor position, it behaves like this:

```
self.vec.push(|aa, bb)
```

If I enter a left parenthesis `(`, it turns to:

```
self.vec.push((|aa), bb)
```

that `)` generates after `aa`. I did not find the documentation to this behavior in eglot documentations or through web search. But I found if I disable eglot by `eglot-shutdown`, this behavior disappears and if I repeat the above process after that, it shows this:

```
self.vec.push((|)aa, bb)
```

Because I am using `electric-pair-mode` along with `eglot`, this is quite annoying as when I enter a `(` when selecting a region of text, two `)`s will be generated. Do you know how I can turn off the eglot parenthesis handling? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This appears to be a Rust specific problem. The Rust LSP server responded the onTypeFormatting suggestion inserting the parenthesis.

```
[jsonrpc] e[17:16:16.575] --> textDocument/onTypeFormatting[20] {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":20,"method":"textDocument/onTypeFormatting","params":{"textDocument":{"uri":"*****/lib.rs"},"options":{"tabSize":2,"insertSpaces":true,"insertFinalNewline":true,"trimFinalNewlines":true},"position":{"line":323,"character":19},"ch":"("}}
[jsonrpc] e[17:16:16.579]   <-- textDocument/onTypeFormatting[20] {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":20,"result":[{"range":{"start":{"line":323,"character":23},"end":{"line":323,"character":23}},"newText":")"}]}
```

By adding `:documentOnTypeFormattingProvider` to `eglot-ignored-server-capabilities` this is solved.